# R regex: How to extract string with one or two digit number within title?

Tags: regex, r

I have a bunch of filenames that are numbered that I would like to be able to extract based on a regex statement.

For example, say I have the following filenames:

`file.names <- paste0("run", 0:99, ".dat.gz")`

If I wanted to extract files 5 through 8, I would need a regex that returns the following:

```
grep("correct_regex", file.names, value=TRUE)
"run5.dat.gz"  "run6.dat.gz"  "run7.dat.gz"  "run8.dat.gz"
```

Or if I wanted to return files 9 through 21, it would return the following:

```
grep("correct_regex", file.names, value=TRUE)
"run9.dat.gz"  "run10.dat.gz" "run11.dat.gz" "run12.dat.gz" "run13.dat.gz" "run14.dat.gz" "run15.dat.gz" "run16.dat.gz" "run17.dat.gz" "run18.dat.gz" "run19.dat.gz" "run20.dat.gz" "run21.dat.gz"
```

The tricky part if developing a regex that extracts the number as opposed to the digits (e.g. `[0-9]`). Any tips to help with this?

Comment: try `grep("run[5-8]\\.dat\\.gz", file.names, value=TRUE)`

Comment: You could do `grep("run[5-8]\\.dat\\.gz", file.names, value=TRUE)`and `grep(paste0("run",paste(9:21, collapse="|"),"\\.dat\\.gz"), file.names, value=TRUE)`. However, why not sorting all the file names in memory and extracting by index?

Comment: 5 - 8: `run[5678]\.dat\.gz`, 9-21: `run(1[0-9]|2[01]|9)\.dat\.gz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also think that Sam's answer is the correct one, but **just in case you also need to quickly extract non-sequential items**, here is how you can easily build the regex you need (these subpatterns are to be used between `"^run` and `[.]dat[.]gz$"`):

- Use `[5-8]` to match all digits from `5` to `8` (as in the current example)
- For non-sequential one-digit values, add the ranges separately (`[1-37-9]` will match `1`, `2`, `3`, `7`, `8`, `9`)
- When you need to combine numbers of different length, use alternations with `(...|...)`:

  - `(1[2-4]|2[89])` - will match `12`, `13`, `14`, `28` and `29`
  - `(2[3-5]|[0-2])` - will match  `23`, `24`, `25`, `0`, `1`, and `2`

In your case, you can use

```
> file.names <- paste0("run", 0:99, ".dat.gz")
> grep("^run[5-8][.]dat[.]gz$", file.names, value=TRUE)
[1] "run5.dat.gz" "run6.dat.gz" "run7.dat.gz" "run8.dat.gz"
>
```

Note that `^` matches the start of string and `$` matches the end of string (so, this regex ensures a full string match).

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a simple function and avoid regexes:

```
get_numbered_filenames <- function(num_vec){
  target <- paste0("run", num_vec, ".dat.gz")
  file.names[file.names %in% target]
}

get_numbered_filenames(9:21)

 [1] "run9.dat.gz"  "run10.dat.gz" "run11.dat.gz" "run12.dat.gz" "run13.dat.gz" "run14.dat.gz"
 [7] "run15.dat.gz" "run16.dat.gz" "run17.dat.gz" "run18.dat.gz" "run19.dat.gz" "run20.dat.gz"
[13] "run21.dat.gz"
```